# Is it possible to parse certificate from base64 form?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, certificate, base64

If I have a certificate file.cer in a base64 form, is it possible to parse it to its values in a normal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28v=VS.400%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a base64 encoded certificate, in PEM format. You can use openssl command to check the data. For example

```
#openssl x509 -in <certificate_file> -text
```

Comment: I don't need to check the data, I need to parse this file, get all the information.

Comment: everything - version, serial number, issuer, public key, encryption algorithm name, sign...

Comment: The openssl command should show you the information that you are looking for. Does it not?

Comment: @Sergey you should probably have added more context (if only with tags) to the question.